# Shuffling pandas DataFrame rows if the values "overlap" between two columns

Tags: sorting, pandas, dataframe, intersection, overlap

I have the following pandas dataframe

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"first_element":[20, 125, 156, 211, 227, 220, 230, 472, 4765], "second_element":[35, 145, 178, 233, 321, 234, 231, 498, 8971], "next":[0.32, 0.04, 0.59, 0.103, 0.37, 0.92, 0.81, 0.24, 0.77]})
df = df[["first_element", "second_element", "next"]]

print(df)
### print(df) outputs:
    first_element  second_element   next
0             20              35  0.320
1            125             145  0.040
2            156             178  0.590
3            211             233  0.103
4            227             321  0.370
5            220             234  0.920
6            230             231  0.810
7            472             498  0.240
8           4765            8971  0.770
```

In this DataFrame, each row is considered an "interval" along a real line, `[first_element, second_element]`, e.g. 20 to 35, 125 to 145.

If I wished to sort `df` based on both columns, I would use `.sort_values()`, i.e.

```
sorted_df = df.sort_values(["first_element", "second_element"], ascending=[True, False])
```

which outputs

```
print(sorted_df)
    first_element  second_element   next
0             20              35  0.320
1            125             145  0.040
2            156             178  0.590
3            211             233  0.103
5            220             234  0.920
4            227             321  0.370
6            230             231  0.810
7            472             498  0.240
8           4765            8971  0.770
```

There are several intervals which intersect/overlap, namely `[211, 233], [220, 234], [227, 321], [230, 231]`. Because `[230, 231]` is a subset of `[211, 233]`, there are several ways to order these two.

My goal is (1) write a function that finds all overlapping "intervals" (the values in the two columns `first_element` and `second_element`) and (2) randomly shuffle these intervals.

The goal (2) sounds very tricky, because one would need to separately shuffle/re-order multiple "groups" of overlapping intervals. For example, let's say our dataframe was larger, and had the following overlapping intervals:

```
[211, 233], [220, 234], [227, 321], [230, 231], [5550, 5879], [5400, 5454]
```

I would want to separately re-shuffle `[211, 233], [220, 234], [227, 321], [230, 231]` and `[5550, 5879], [5400, 5454]`, not mix up the subsets of overlapping intervals.

There are several ways to shuffle rows with pandas, e.g. shuffle by the index

```
def shuffle_by_index(df):
    index = list(df.index)
    random.shuffle(index)
    df = df.ix[index]
    df.reset_index()
    return df
```

or use `sklearn`

```
import sklearn.utils
shuffled = sklearn.utils.shuffle(df)
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
```

but (1) how does one search for all overlapping intervals in a pythonic/pandas way and (2) how do I select these subsets of overlapping intervals and only shuffle those individually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not the best way to solve it, but it gives your desired results. I have left second part for you.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"first_element":[20, 125, 156, 211, 227, 220, 230, 472, 4765], "second_element":[35, 145, 178, 233, 321, 234, 231, 498, 8971], "next":[0.32, 0.04, 0.59, 0.103, 0.37, 0.92, 0.81, 0.24, 0.77]})
df = df[["first_element", "second_element", "next"]]

sorted_df = df.sort_values(["first_element", "second_element"], ascending=[True, False])
sorted_df.reset_index(0, inplace = True)

prev_min = sorted_df.first_element.iloc[0]
prev_max = sorted_df.second_element.iloc[0]

labels = []
label_counter = 1
labels.append(label_counter)

for rowIndex in xrange(1, sorted_df.shape[0]):
    row = sorted_df.iloc[rowIndex]

    if row.first_element > prev_max:
        # totally different interval, may be overlapping interval
        prev_min = row.first_element
        prev_max = row.second_element
        label_counter += 1
        labels.append(label_counter)
    elif row.first_element >= prev_min:
        prev_max = max(prev_max, row.second_element)
        labels.append(label_counter)

sorted_df['overlapping_index'] = labels

# group sorted_df by overlapping index, and randomly select the save interval group
```

Comment: I understand that the last line of code outputs a pandas dataframe with all overlapping intervals. I'm not sure though how to then (1) separate these into individual groups of intersecting intervals and (2) randomly shuffle these indices such that the final output is the original dataframe.